# Format document - indentation on object initialization is wrong

Tags: c#, visual-studio, indentation, visual-studio-2022

The problem is the indentation on object initializers' indentation when Format document is run (CTRL + K, CTRL + D) in Visual Studio 2022.

**Current:**

```
Person person = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Doe"
    };
```

**Expected:**

```
Person person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe"
};
```

When doing arrays/list object initialization, the indentation works as I want it.

What setting in Visual Studio is it that causes this?

I have tried turning on/off these settings with no luck getting the expected:

`Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> Indentation -> Indent block contents`

`Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> Indentation -> Indent open and close braces`

I have tried resetting all Visual Studio settings, and tried creating a new solution, and no luck either.

Comment: Do you have a .editorconfig file in your project/solution?

Comment: yes, and I have tried changing it as well the same settings as on this post. And also tried making a new solution project without one. Same results.

Comment: Bear in mind that the .editorconfig overrides settings you set in VS

Comment: I understand, but I even tried making a different solution to simply test format document and it still is the same result.

Comment: Is this normal behavior that it indents like this? I tried resetting VS settings too, still same results.

Comment: No, this is not normal

Comment: Oh, check for .editorconfig files in folders above your solution, too. I'm not sure there's a limit on how far it traverses up...

Comment: I checked, no editorconfigs above my solution. Also tried just now creating a new solution in a completely different drive with no other projects/editorconfigs. Still same result - I will try now reinstalling VS and update if that fixes it.

Comment: No luck even uninstalling VS completely and installing it. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Playing around with those settings, I can't even make it do the indentation you're seeing...

Comment: Maybe click General -> Generate .editorconfig from ..., and look at the result to see if there's anything suspicious?

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT your answer didn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: @Zecret This is really strange, I have tried many ways to restore the situation you said. You can go to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio to report related issues.

Comment: Is this your whole code file? If no, do you mind sharing the whole file or at least the whole member containing your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used .razor files and not .cs files. .cs files work fine.

The razor team has a problem with correct indentation when formatting document.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you indent open and close brace.

This is the code format when I checked indent open and close brace.

[image]

You can fix your code formatting by following these steps:

1. Create a new .editorconfig under your project

[image]

[image]

2. Open .editorconfig, go to Whitespace
3. Find the indent open and close brace to uncheck, and save the settings

[image]

4. ctrl+k, ctrl+d. Then you will find that your code format is

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I have initialisers which, whatever I did, got wrecked by VS2022 as soon as I typed ; or saved the file.

I've now included them in a txt file and I can do what I like.